# Simple inequality problem (somewhat related to complexity)

Tags: inequality, computational-complexity

If $0\leq a, b, c \leq R$ and
$$
0\leq a+b-2c \leq \epsilon
$$
how can we upper bound the quantity
$$
a^n + b^n -2c^n
$$
where $n\geq1$ is an integer.

My crude bound, assuming $a-c \geq 0$ and $b-c \geq0$, is $\epsilon^n$, but I want to know if there is a nice way to show that $a^n + b^n - 2c^n \leq \epsilon^n$ without any assumption (or maybe other relevant results)

Comment: there is no upper bound. Take  $b = 0, a = 2c + \epsilon$ and make $c \to +\infty$

Comment: @NN2 I edited the problem. Can we say the same thing if a,b,c are bounded above? I think the upper bound then should depend on epsilon and R